# Reconstruct directories from file MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Thanks for your help.

The problem is:

I need the user to select a file based on an extension lets say .tif. I used the standard method, i.e.

```
[flnm,locn]=uigetfile({'*.tif','Image files'}, 'Select an image');
ext = '.tif';
```

But I need to fetch other image files from other subdirectories. Say the directory name returned to `locn` is: `/user/blade/checklist/exp1/trial_1/run_1/exp001.tif`. Image goes to `exp100.tif`.

I want to access:

```
/user/blade/checklist/exp1/trial_1/run_2/exp001.tif.
```

Also access:

```
/user/blade/checklist/exp1/trial_2/run_2/exp001.tif.
```

Up to **`trial_n`**

But if I list directory in `/user/blade/checklist/exp1/`, I get all folders therein from where I can reconstruct the right path. The naming structure is orderly.

My current solution is

```
[flnm,locn]=uigetfile({'*.tif','Image files'}, 'Select an image');
ext = '.tif';
parts = strsplit(locn, '/');
f = fullfile(((parts{end-5}),(parts{end-4}),(parts{end-3}),(parts{end-2}),(parts{end-1}));
```

Which is really ugly and I also lose the first `/`. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the file location as you did; note a small change I've made to make use of the variable `ext`.

```
ext = '.txt';
[flnm,locn]=uigetfile({['*',ext]}, 'Select an image');
parts = strsplit(locn,'/');
root = parts(1:end-4);
```

`parts` has 2 information - 1) path of the selected file; 2) path of your working folder, `checklist`, which you need. So `root` has the working folder.

Then, list out all the files you wanted, and put them in a cell array.

The file names should contain partial (subfolder) paths; it's not difficult to follow the pattern.

```
flist = {'trial_1/run_1/exp001.tif', ...
    'trial_1/run_1/exp002.tif', ...
    'trial_1/run_2/exp001.tif', ...
    'trial_2/run_1/exp001.tif', ...
    'trial_2/run_2/exp001.tif'};
```

I just enumerated a few; you can use a `for` loop to automatically generate `trial_n` and `expxxx.tif`. An example code to generate the complete file list (but not "full paths") -

```
flist = cell(10*2*100,1);

for ii = 1:10
    for jj = 1:2
        for kk = 1:100
            flist{sub2ind([10,2,100],ii,jj,kk)} = ...
                sprintf('trial_%d/run_%d/exp%03d%s', ii,...
                jj, kk, ext);
        end
    end
end
```

Finally, use `strjoin` to concatenate the first part (your working folder) and second part (needed files in subfolders). Use `cellfun` to call `strjoin` for each cell in the file list cell array, so for every file you want you get a full path.

```
full_flist = cellfun(@(x) strjoin([root, x],'/'), ...
    flist, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Example output -

```
>> locn
locn =
/home/user/Downloads/exp1/trial_1/run_1/
>> for ii = 1:5
full_flist{ii}
end
ans =
/home/user/Downloads/trial_1/run_1/exp001.tif
ans =
/home/user/Downloads/trial_1/run_1/exp002.tif
ans =
/home/user/Downloads/trial_1/run_2/exp001.tif
ans =
/home/user/Downloads/trial_2/run_1/exp001.tif
ans =
/home/user/Downloads/trial_2/run_2/exp001.tif
>>
```

---

Note: You can either use

```
strjoin(str1, str2, '/')
```

or

```
sprintf('%s/%s', str1, str2)
```

They are equivalent.